# How to expect what kind of props will be given from React Native component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making app with using React Native.

There is a TextInput as we all know. And it's usage looks like this.

```
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}
  />
```

Here, 'text' props is given from RN, then we can use it.

But I wonder how can we know the 'text' props will be given? 
I'm asking this because it's not in the API document but only in example.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext

> Callback that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed
>   text is passed as an argument to the callback handler.

Actually, there is. But I think it's not clear.

Should I find those like this way? Is there better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m slightly confused on your question. 
However, You can pass any custom function to onTextChange.

OnTextChange={this.customFunction(text)}

customFunction(text) {
      Console.log(text)

}
This function would fire every time the text input changes.

Comment: What I mean is that, how can you know you will be given 'text' props from OnTextChange. This case, we could get it from the documentation but what about other cases? Is there no way to know that without document?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Yes this is difficult to find out. What you should google is component Proptypes. getDefaultProps() would be where you should start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've actually found the question you're asking incredibly frustrating when working with npm packages with bad docs.... I normally have to go digging through the source code to actually find a good answer... You're not alone!

Heres a link to an npm package where you can see how they construct proptypes https://github.com/ThePaulMcBride/react-native-smart-picker/blob/master/src/index.js